# Magento 2: Requested store is not found in admin/catalog/category

Tags: php, magento2

when im clicking on categories from admin/catalog/categories its showing :

There has been an error processing your request
Requested store is not found

As im getting all catgory on frontend side but not on admin side.....

Answer (score 0):

**Run the following commands in your database.**

```
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';

UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';

UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
```